# Returning multiple objects without key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return multiple objects without their index, however, I cannot find a way using Objects. This is what I have tried so far, am I missing something?

```
  const fields = [
    'name',
    'age',
    'address'
  ];

  const builtFields = []

  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    builtFields.push(
      {
        [fields[i]]: { type: '' }
      }
    )
  }

  fields: Object.assign({}, builtFields)

  
  console.log(fields)

  Outputs:

  fields: {
     0: { name: { type: '' } },
     1: { age: { type: '' } },
     2: { address: { type: '' } }
  }
```

```
Desired output:

  fields: {
     name: { type: '' },
     age: { type: '' },
     address: { type: '' }
  }
```

Comment: Small oversight? `Object.assign({}, ...builtFields)` But as long as you don’t need the array version for something else, you can create the final object directly by starting with `const builtFields = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently assigning the array **entries** to the object while you actually want to add each array **item** (which is an entry) to the empty object:

```
fields: Object.assign({}, ...builtFields)
```

As a shortest solution:

```js
const fields = [
  'name',
  'age',
  'address'
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(fields.map(x => [x, { type: '' }]));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for